# Is there any way to get all sub directories from a given path?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, directory-structure

`Directory.GetDirectories` returns only the given path's sub-directories but I would like to list all the subs, and their subs all the way to the end.

I'm thinking of a recursive function, but I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another [Directory.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\data", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Does the job, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
new DirectoryInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location /* or any other location */)
.EnumerateDirectories("*"/*or any other pattern*/,SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You can modify all arguments as needed.